# How to change default language in Knoppix ISO?

Tags: iso-image, language, linux-distributions, knoppix

Is it possible to modify the default language in the Knoppix ISO file instead of manually changing it during boot?

Distro in question: `KNOPPIX_V7.2.0CD-2013-06-16-EN.iso`

Note: Latest versions are only in English and Deutch by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ( http://knoppix.net/wiki/Knoppix_Remastering_Howto ) you can find instructions about the customization of the knoppix (>7.0) distribution.

As you need to apply only "minor" changes (adding the "LANG=.." parameter as a default boot-option of the knoppix boot-loader [eg: "LANG=it" for Italian]), you need only to apply "Changes outside from chroot enviroment", as described in the related paragraph of the above linked page.

It might be useful to check other boot-related parameters that can be customized, here: http://knoppix.net/wiki/Cheat_Codes

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to modify the ISO in Windows?

Comment: First of all, I suggest you to try working with ISO files under Linux: it's not so difficult, with "friendly" distributions like Ubuntu or Fedora (or Mint... or any other "recent" desktop distribution). If you  want to stick to windows (but please, consider I'm not a windows expert), you can look to the [Virtual CD-ROM Control Panel](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38780) to "open" the original ISO image so to apply your changes, and then to [isoCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iso-creator-cs/) to create the new ISO images. But, again, I'm not a windows expert